# UIApplicationDelegate Functions in Other Classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

Is it possible to conform to `UIApplicationDelegate` and successfully have all of the functions that are called on startup/close called in ANY class?  For instance, if I have a class where it would be a good idea to save a lot of data on the app's closing, but I don't want to create a reference to it in the App Delegate, would it be OK to just have it conform the the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, then perform it's save in `(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`?

To be more succinct: is there any danger in having multiple classes conform to `UIApplicationDelegate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one delegate can be designated for any object at any one time.  It sounds like what you really want to do here is register for notifications.

Or, if there are no notifications for the things you want, set your application delegate to post custom notifications to any listeners in all the various classes you want to do work when certain app delegate things get fired.

And to answer your succinct question, there shouldn't be "danger" in having multiple classes conform to `UIApplicationDelegate`, but again, you can only have one delegate answering to `UIApplication` at any one time.

Comment: But looking in the documentation, they don't ever warn about multiple classes conforming to `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: @CodaFi, you can have other classes conform to UIApplicationDelegate, but how are you going to assign multiple delegates to your UIApplication object?

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` looks promising.

Comment: @CodaFi you can't hold two values in a single variable.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to set the delegate as your class and is also not possible to have two delegates.. 
What you can do is register for notification.

```
UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
```

etc etc.. check documentation of [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification) in `UIApplication` Class Reference

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear... I just want to know if it's possible, not a workaround.  See my discussion with Michael Dautermann for more.

Comment: @CodaFi this not a work around. At a time you can only have one delegate that will get these method calls. So one thing is that you set this delegate to your class may be in your view did load or where you create the object of your class and get all the method calls in your class not in AppDelegate class. And as far as my opinion there shouldn't be any problem. But I would suggest Notification instead of setting delegate. Now decision is upto you.